# Showing $|\sum_{k=1} ^n e^{\frac{2 \pi i k^2}{n}}| = \sqrt{n} $

Tags: ring-theory, complex-numbers, summation

I would like to show the above result, with as little brute forcing as possible (i.e. trying to avoid a clunky induction).

Upon expanding the LHS, we see

$|\sum_{k=1} ^n e^{\frac{2 \pi i k^2}{n}}|^2 = n + 2 \sum_{ p<q} cos( 2 \pi /n (p^2 -q^2))$ so we wish this summand to be 0, but I don't know if this leads to an easier problem to solve.

I would like to try use some more general ring properties- perhaps the ring generated by the $ \{ e^{\frac{2 \pi i k^2}{n}} \} $ under the usual $ +, \times $ forms a lattice which relates to the $n$ somehow as a distance of points (this is the only way I see how to relate the norm to the ring directly), but this again is just speculation I don't see how to use.

Comment: You probably need to assume $n$ is odd. The expression $|\cdots| = \sqrt{n}$ is false for all even $n$ I have tried.

Comment: This is the Gauss sum. For example the sum is zero for $n=4k+2$.

Comment: See [Gauss sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum#Generalized_quadratic_Gauss_sums). For $p$ prime you can define $\chi(n)= (\frac{n}{p})$ the Legendre symbol and show it is its own discrete Fourier transform. For $p$ non-prime it is more complicated as a  product of two quadratic non-residues doesn't have to be a square.